# date toISOString with the initialized timezone on dayjs not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, timezone, dayjs

Hey I'm initializing a date on string format to format to ISOString:

"2021-06-01"

dayjs("2021-06-01").tz("Africa/Lagos").toISOString();

the result is:

'2021-06-01T04:00:00.000Z'

currently with the system timezone, how can I print with the initialized timezone?

Comment: Do you have dayjs.extend(utc) and dayjs.extend(timezone) ?
Could you try dayjs.tz("2021-06-01", "Africa/Lagos").toISOString(); instead to see the result.

Comment: Check if you have your plugins correctly set : https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/timezone

Comment: I'm initializing the dayjs at the begining like this:
const dayjs = require('dayjs');
const utc = require('dayjs/plugin/utc');
const timezone = require('dayjs/plugin/timezone');
dayjs.extend(utc);
dayjs.extend(timezone);

Comment: And what happened when you pass the time as a parameter to .tz() -  dayjs.tz("2021-06-01", "Africa/Lagos").toISOString()

Answer (score 0):

this syntax doesnt work:

```
dayjs("2021-06-01").tz("Africa/Lagos").toISOString()
```

use this instead

```
dayjs.tz("2021-06-01", "Africa/Lagos").toISOString()
```